# Android base layout with buttons to use in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-layout, include

I'm developing an Android app where many activities need to have 4 buttons in their layout, one in each corner of the screen. The behavior of these buttons is always the same, regardless the current activity (for example, a sound off/sound on toggle button, a Help button, etc). I've designed a base_layout with the top right and top left buttons, and used the  tag in the activities' layout. I've also created a BaseActivity class that has the behavior of the buttons, so every activity that includes them inherits from this class. So far it works okay, but if I add one of the buttons at the bottom of the screen, this layout overlaps with each activity's layout, so I only see the base_layout and not the activity layout.

Here's the base_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_atras"
    android:src="@drawable/flecha_atras"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:contentDescription="Atrás"/>

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sonido"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:button="@drawable/sonido_selector"
    android:checked="true"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_ayuda"
    android:src="@drawable/ayuda"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="Ayuda"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is part of the layout from an activity that uses it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

<include
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/base_layout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@style/TextoTitulo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/titulo_menu" />

<!--more stuff here that I'm cutting because it's irrelevant to the question--->
</LinearLayout>
```

What is the best way to achieve the 4 global buttons on each corner of the screen in every activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and the [`merge`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge) tag.

base_layout.xml would look something like

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout">
    .
    .
    .
```

And the activity xml would like something like

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        layout="@layout/base_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks. Using this, the base_layout shows the 3 buttons all on the top left corner, on top of each other. I'm guessing there are some new attributes I should add to each button...can you help with that?

Comment: I mean, before, the buttons were in a RelativeLayout, but now I understand that tag is erased and the buttons go after the merge tag opens and before it closes, so I'm not sure what attributes to use to position the buttons in their right places

Comment: Did you add the right constraints on each view? Check out https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/